# Updating "Origin Connection Attempts" property of Cloudfront through CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to modify the `Origin Connection Attempts` property of CloudFront through the CloudFormation template. I referred to the AWS document but I couldn't find any corresponding key for this property. Any information on that? Here is the doc link, I referred-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-customoriginconfig.html#aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-customoriginconfig-properties

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That feature is only a couple months old and cloudformation tends to lag behind service updates. Part of the reason for terraform's rise in popularity.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally found the document which specifies the key for modifying `Origin Connection Attempts`, the key name is `ConnectionAttempts`. More details can be fount on -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-origin-connectionattempts